# WebScraping - Parsel: XPath in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape medium.com
I am using the following code:

```
from parsel import Selector
def get_trending(html):
    selector = Selector(text=html)

    text = selector.xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/a/div/h2")
    # h2 = text.xpath("//h2/text()")
    print(text)

response = requests.get("https://medium.com")
opponents = get_trending(response.text)
opponents
```

For some reason, it is giving an empty list as a result. I tried it with another h2 and I got the result I wanted. What might be the problem?
Here is the screenshot when I try the xpath in the inspect tool it is working as shown in the image below.

[image]

Comment: that xpath doesnt match nothing on website, that contains means h2 with class substring "*by jz eg ca cx ka js jt kb jv jx hr cb*", all characters are inside a class, not each one. What do you wanna extact?

Comment: Are you sure you are scraping medium, and not some other website? Especially given the variable name `opponents` :)). Your XPATH locator doesn't match any element on that page. Good luck though.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I just took that name because I was following a tutorial and just getting to know how it was working. I thought of changing it after I am sure how things are working

Comment: I am trying to extract the trending article names from the home page. @Wonka

Comment: I actually tried the xpath in the inspect tool and it seems to select/highlight it in that but in code, it is returning [] as the result.

Comment: @KarthikBhandary only "Trending on Medium" or all below?

Comment: The names of all the articles listed in the Trending on Medium. I am trying to make a sub-package where the functions are available. This is just one of the functions I am trying to make where when I run get_trending() I would get the names of the trending articles

Comment: Ok, so  I offered you a solution below, however I'm bound to comment on your latest edit: that long, long XPATH is so fragile and so long, it shouldn't be used. It's just ... bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get those elements you're looking for using BeautifulSoup instead of Parsel -- you can adapt the code to Parsel if you are so inclined, and you can edit the class content as well to suit your usecase:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

headers= {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get("https://medium.com/", headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.select('h2[class^="by j"]')
for x in elements:
    print(x.text)
```

Result in terminal:

```
No One Really Tells You The Hardest Part Of Getting Older
A good day with Jeff
4 Secrets of Emotionally Stable People
Thought experiment in the National Library of Thailand
Unnatural Keys
Business Model Generation & Playing to Win
On the nature of elegance
It’s Time to Re-Design How We Think
Report from a Relationship
The Secret to Good Photography
A good day with Jeff
How I Turned My Company’s Docs into a Searchable Database with OpenAI
Thought experiment in the National Library of Thailand
What We’re Reading: Always Take a Peek at the Comments
A Contrarian Bet Against Generative AI: The Value of Being Uniquely Human
Why an Engineering Manager Should Not Review Code
```

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Can I know what the headers' purpose? @BarrythePlatipus

Comment: Header's purpose is to mimic a browser's request.

Comment: Yeah ok. Actually, before I went with Parcel I tried with bs but it would not work no matter what! I will try to implement this and let you know.

Comment: Also, what is ^= in `h2[class^="by j"]` doing?

Comment: That is trying to locate all `h2` elements where `class` attribute starts with `by j`.

Comment: ok. The code you gave is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath, this is for the list below and Trending on Medium:

```
text = selector.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'pw-homefeed-item') or contains(@class,'pw-trending')]//h2")
```

Comment: Thanks, man for the code! But I am going with Beautiful soup.

Comment: Is compatible Xpath and BeautifulSoup